# Page MetaTypes in Composite C1: How to display in the template?

Tags: c1-cms

In my template I have an h1 I need to have in a specific place in the template. I've added a page metatype and that makes sense:

[image]

I can't figure out how to output the value. Seems like it should be extremely easy.

I'm using XML templates and here is where the data lives (I believe):

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using anyt kind of Function here in [example](https://docs.c1.orckestra.com/Functions/XSLT/XSLTFAQ?q=How%20to%20render%20values%20from%20Page%20meta%20types%3F) XSLT function is used.
So you have to create function and add it to your xml template

Hope this will help.